# Google Calendar API is not real time?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I follow this sample
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android
to try the Google Calendar API.

The sample works (can get events from Google calendar) when I click `Call Google Calendar API` button.

But when I use Google's app `Calendar` to add a new event or delete an existing event, then click `Call Google Calendar API` button again, the sample still return old events list.

After clicking `Call Google Calendar API` button a few times, the returned events become up-to-date finally.

Is Google Calendar API not real time? Or how to change the sample code to make sure the API return the up-to-date events each time?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems Google needs some time to sync data. If I waited a few seconds then  clicking `Call Google Calendar API` button, the returned data would be up-to-date.